# Muffed Kickoff Out Of Bounds

Tags: american-football

I don't understand this situation:

- Team A kicks a kickoff, it exceeds the 20 yards and, in flight, a player of the team A (The kicking team) touches it, without having possession, the ball goes directly out ouf bounds, without being touched by a player of the team B (The receiving team), what's the rule? Where is the ball placed in this case? Where it goes out of bounds, right?

Answer (score 1):

So you are saying on a kickoff a kicking team player touches the ball after it becomes legal to touch (i.e. goes ten yards) and does not gain possession and the bal goes out of bounds before the receiving team touches the ball.

That is covered in [the NFL rulebook.](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-rulebook/#article-3-free-kick-out-of-bounds) I believe it considered simply as a kick out of bounds. Usually works out to be the 40 yard line (25 yards from the kickoff spot).

> ARTICLE 3. FREE KICK OUT OF BOUNDS
>
> The kicking team may not kick the ball out of bounds or be the last to
> touch the ball before it goes out of bounds between the goal lines. If
> the receiving team is the last to touch the ball before it goes out of
> bounds, the receiving team puts the ball in play at the inbounds spot.
>
> Penalty: For a kickoff out of bounds: The receiving team may elect to
> take possession of the ball 25 yards from the spot of the kick at the
> inbounds line on the side of the field where the ball went out of
> bounds, or at the out-of-bounds spot.

Note that punts are different. (And there's a different yardage for safety kicks)